# Change div background based on file chooser choice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way to have a div background image change when the user chooses an image from a form input.  As you can see below I have a input type of file.  Once the user chooses the file they want I would like the div#imgHolder to change the background based on the file chosen.  Any thoughts?

```
<div id="simpleDialog" style="width: 350px; height: 350px; display:none;" scrolltop="0">
  <br>  
  <div id="imgHolder" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-image: url(images/gray.png)"></div>
  <br>
  <form id="userForm" align="center">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Artist Info</legend>
        <input type="file" name="artistImage" id="artistImage" style="border: none;float:left"><br><br>
        <label for="text" style="float:left">Enter URL:</label>
        <input type="text" name="website" id="website" value="" required="required">                
      </fieldset>
  </form>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" /> 
  <input type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you tagged this [html5](/questions/tagged/html5), you understand that this is an advanced browser-feature.

What you're asking for will require the FileReader, available in [most all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader) (even IE).

```
// Bind to the change event of our file input
$("input[name='myFileSelect']").on("change", function(){

    // Get a reference to the fileList
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];

    // If no files were selected, or no FileReader support, return
    if ( !files.length || !window.FileReader ) return;

    // Only proceed if the selected file is an image
    if ( /^image/.test( files[0].type ) ) {

        // Create a new instance of the FileReader
        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Read the local file as a DataURL
        reader.readAsDataURL( files[0] );

        // When loaded, set image data as background of page
        reader.onloadend = function(){

            $("html").css("background-image", "url(" + this.result + ")");

        }

    }

});​
```

I just tested the above code in Internet Explorer 10, Chrome 19/21, Firefox 12/13, and Opera 11.64 and found that it worked with no problems.

Older browsers, which don't support the FileReader, will just remain silent. No images shown, no exceptions raised.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/K3A9r/

Comment: @JohnathanSampson  Would this cause an issue if I'm running this from a jQuery popup?  In fiddle it works but on my page it does not.

Comment: @MatthewLancaster I would need to see your code, but in principle no - nothing here should be prevented by a modal element. What issue are you having?

Comment: @JohnathanSampson here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lank81/DSsnb/  Of course it works in here :).  I've tried with Firefox 13.0 and Chrome 19.x

Comment: @MatthewLancaster When it doesn't work, do you see any output in the console?

Comment: @JonhathanSampson Actually nothing.  The console doesn't output anything.  Would I be able to send you my HTML/JS/CSS files to glance over?

Comment: @MatthewLancaster That would be fine.

Comment: @MatthewLancaster Can you not link to your live page from here?

Comment: it's not up yet so it's all local.  Do you mind if I send it via DropBox?  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77055142/index.html - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77055142/js/jquery.blockUI.js - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/77055142/js/popup.js

Comment: @MatthewLancaster You could place it in your public folder on DB and post a link here.

Comment: [19 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11008362/283863) I posted an answer with the same thing, and I got a mysterious downvote saying HTML5 is only in new browsers... and eventually, Matthew didn't notice it.

Comment: @Derek I'm not a big fan of downvoting, so I cannot justify anybody's downvote on your answer. That being said, it was a bit messy, though technically it was taking the correct approach.

Comment: @MatthewLancaster Thank you for uploading your files. I'll take a look at them shortly.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I figured out the issue.  The pop-up is losing focus so it's not picking up the change event in the pop-up.  Once I changed .on to .live it worked.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MatthewLancaster You don't want to change `.on` to `.live`. The `.live` method has been deprecated. Show me the `.live` line of code you have and I'll show you the appropriate replacement to use event-delegation.

Comment: @JonathanSampson $("input[name='artistImage']").live("change",function(){

Comment: @MatthewLancaster Is #simpledialog on the page when it loads, or do you programmatically add it to the DOM with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

If you want to access pictures that are on the local computer, you can do that with [HTML5's File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

[For example:](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files)

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
          reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want the submit to to be when the image changes.  When the user picks an image from the file chooser I'd like the div background to change.  This way they can make sure they are happy with image they chose in which they want to represent the URL they chose.

Comment: This code will not work, because the user is choosing the file from the local computer using the input file field. The code above is setting the bg image from the text in another field. (Added to justify my downvote)

Comment: This code *will* work. It accesses the local computer, and read the image file as DataURL.

Comment: This will not work in all browsers. This will work only in broswers which support latest HTML5 features. We cannot ask the users to upgrade the software to use this feature.

Comment: @kiranvj - I think you should see what tags is there first. You have missed something. There *is* a HTML5 tag.

Comment: @Derek is correct that I was looking for a HTML5 answer.  I'm not worried about the browser issues.  I up voted your answer Derek but Jonathan's fit better for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a jQuery, on click on image of form input to change the css attribute `background-image` of `#imgHolder`.

Comment: I wasn't sure if onClick would work since the image wouldn't be selected right at onClick.

Comment: yes you are correct, what you can do is that when you do onClick, just read the src attribute of img and use that as background-url, make sure to do return false after doing the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Due to browsers security modal it will not allow you to access a file from local computer and show it in the browser **unless you use HTML5 FileReader() feature** (which unfortunatly all browsers will not support as of now) .

Comment: <input type="file" name="artistImage"> is the input in which the user will choose a file from their PC.  The Input text type is so a users artist webpage can be saved with the graphic they wish to use.

Comment: @Derek : Enter url is the label for another input box to enter website. Also read the question description. There its mentioned the user will choose a file. type="file" is used for file upload.